# PIVOT - change returned table value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a query:

```
SELECT
    PatientId, Parameter, AVG(CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), [Value]))) as [Value]
FROM 
    ExaminationDetails
JOIN 
    Examinations 
ON
    Examinations.Id = ExaminationDetails.ExaminationId
WHERE 
    Parameter IN ('BLD_SYS', 'BLD_DIA')
GROUP BY 
    PatientId, Parameter
```

Which return the result:

```
PatientId | Parametr | Value
----------+----------+-------
3         | BLD_DIA  | 96
----------+----------+-------
98        | BLD_DIA  | 89
----------+----------+-------
3         | BLD_SYS  | 137
----------+----------+-------
98        | BLD_SYS  | 133
----------+----------+------
```

Is there way to change returned table value when `BLD_DIA` and `BLD_SYS` are returned as columns:

```
 PatientId | BLD_DIA | BLD_SYS
 ----------+---------+--------
    3      |  96     |  137
 ----------+---------+--------
    98     |  89     |  133
 ----------+---------+--------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.PatientId, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'BLD_SYS' THEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, Value) END) as BLD_SYS,
       AVG(CASE WHEN Parameter = 'BLD_DIA' THEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, Value) END) as BLD_DIA
FROM ExaminationDetails ed JOIN
     Examinations e
     ON e.Id = ed.ExaminationId
WHERE ed.Parameter IN ('BLD_SYS', 'BLD_DIA')
GROUP BY e.PatientId;
```

Notes:

- No subquery or CTE is needed.
- You are converting `Value` to an `INT`.  To be safe, use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CONVERT()`.  (SQL Server can rearrange operations resulting in unexpected type conversion errors.)
- The average of integers is an *integer*.  So `AVG(1, 2)` is `1`, not `1.5`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I see no reason to convert `value` to a string before converting to a number.  If it is already a number, remove the `TRY_CONVERT()`.

Answer (score 2):

I am enhancing your query using CTE and conditional aggregation

```
with cte as (
    SELECT
        PatientId, Parameter
        , AVG(CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), [Value]))) as [Value]
    FROM 
        ExaminationDetails
    JOIN 
        Examinations 
    ON
        Examinations.Id = ExaminationDetails.ExaminationId
    WHERE 
        Parameter IN ('BLD_SYS', 'BLD_DIA')
    GROUP BY 
        PatientId, Parameter
)
select PatientId
    , max(case when Parameter='BLD_DIA' then [Value] end) BLD_DIA
    , max(case when Parameter='BLD_SYS' then [Value] end) BLD_DIA
from cte
group by PatientId
```